# How to change the style of a combobox to a label or hyperlink in WPF?

Tags: wpf, combobox, wpf-controls, controltemplate

I want to change the style of a combo box control to look like a hyperlink.

When user clicks on the hyperlink ( combo box) it show options in the combobox to select.

The idea is that I want combo box control to display as a plain text ( more readable form).

If anybody created this type of sytle please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could edit the ComboBox template and replace the ContentPresenter with a Hyperlink-style button. This should work pretty well, and it is just a bit of XAML coding. You can find the original ComboBox template [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsamples#themes), or using Expression Blend.

**EDIT:**
OK, well, you have a ComboBox template which looks something like this (extremely simplified!):

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Grid>
        <!-- The popup that is displayed after you clicked on the ComboBox. -->
        <Popup IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
               Placement="Bottom"/>

        <!-- The button that is used to open the drop down. -->
        <ToggleButton x:Name="btnOpenDropDown"
                      IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>

        <!-- The control which displays the currently selected item. -->
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPres"
                          Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Actually, it is a bit more complicated because the ToggleButton must *occupy* the whole width (since the drop down should open whereever you click on the ComboBox), but it should *display* only on the right of the content. However, for your scenario, we can neglect this since you will not have a drop down button.

Now, since you only want to display the content as a hyperlink and no button besides it, you no longer need a distinction between ContentPresenter and ToggleButton. Therefore, instead of using a separate ContentPresenter, you could use the ToggleButton to present the content since it also has a Content property. Something like that:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Grid>
        <!-- The popup that is displayed after you clicked on the ComboBox. -->
        <Popup IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
               Placement="Bottom"/>

        <!-- The button that is used to open the drop down AND to display the content (now). -->
        <ToggleButton x:Name="btnOpenDropDown"
                      Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                      IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Of course, there are some additional properties to move from the ContentPresenter to the ToggleButton.

Now, all you have to do is define another template for the ToggleButton which looks like a Hyperlink (and then assign this template to the ToggleButton above). Actually, this should not be difficult assuming that your content is always a string (again, simplified!):

```
<Style x:Key="hyperlinkButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                           TextDecorations="Underline"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This simplified code shows how you could do it. There are certainly other ways, and it still involves some work for you as the example was simplified. However, I cannot offer you the complete code.

Comment: Thanks, gehho.. somehow I am not able to do it .. it will be great if you hava XAML snippet for this..